# Are Test Data Factory Methods Dangerous or Beneficial?

Tags: java, unit-testing, design-patterns, junit

While unit testing with JUnit, I ran into a problem and I want to know if there is a standard solution.

I began using Podam to generate randomized test data, but a coworker correctly remarked that this could lead to unexpected unit test failures. On the one hand this is obviously bad and could make debugging a real pain. On the other hand it could be doing its job by highlighting a code problem.

I identified what I believe to be 3 approaches to solving the issue. Did I miss any options? Are any of these considered standard practice?

1. Factory Method to Generate Randomized Test Data
2. Factory Method to Return Standard Data
3. Handcrafted approach, where there is no factory. Each unit test internally declares its own input data and expected output.

Further, I think each approach has the following pros and cons. Am I missing any important design considerations?

Pros:

1. Robust testing, easy creation, semi-deterministic through overriding generated values.
2. Easy creation, easy debugging.
3. Moderately robust testing and moderately easy to debug.

Cons:

1. Unexpected unit test failure (but at least you caught the issue). Harder to debug.
2. Non-robust testing
3. Human error, redundant and verbose code, less maintainable, diverse implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good unit test needs to do its job and focus on robust testing.

I prefer option 1. Using randomized data may lead to unexpected unit test failures, but at the end of the day this is a good thing because you are covering every technically possible scenario, including scenarios a developer would not think of.

Option 1 may lend itself to a bit more work debugging, but if the methods being tested are simple then this is not likely to be an important amount of overhead. If the methods being tested are extremely complex, it would likely be difficult to debug anyway and probably needs to be broken up.

Options 2 and 3 introduce human error. Minimizing human error is a key goal of any program. 3 is also verbose and unmaintainable. Those issues are likely to eventually end up costing more time and effort than whatever would be dedicated to an extra bit of debugging.

My guess is that #1 will take less time and effort in the long run. That's only a guess and not the main concern. The main concern is that #1 is the proper way to ensure a robust test is executed.

Comment: Unfortunately the thread is put on hold, so I can't add a full answer (you can find more here: http://qala.io/blog/randomized-testing.html), but yes - randomization may lead to unexpected failures. Can be that developer missed a bug, or he didn't know about some behaviour or simply the generator is written incorrectly. To fight with these a) run Unit tests hundreds/thousands times locally before committing (IntelliJ has such option in Run Configuration) b) and for Component & System tests - you can also log or create reports with the data that you used in tests to reproduce the issue easier.